# Rowsums conditional on column name

Tags: r, dplyr, rowsum

My data.frage looks like this:

```
   VAR1 VAR2 AUS1 AUS2 AUS3 AUS4 ... AUS56 VAR3 VAR4
   A    D    23   234  34   856  ... 99    0    FCK
   B    D    55   76   55   36   ... 6456  0    XYC
```

I'd like R to add a new variable `AUS` which shows the rowsums of the variables `AUS1` to `AUS56`, preferably with dplyr. `AUS1` to `AUS56` can then be deleted.

Comment: Consider using the tidy 'long' format for the data, where `AUS` is one column, and the number that comes after is another column. Then you'll aggregate easily with the most traditional `dplyr` verbs like `group_by` and `summarise`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try use `rowSums` in combination with `grep`:

```
df %>% mutate(AUS_sum = rowSums(.[grep("AUS", names(.))]))
```

Comment: I wonder if this could be done using `dplyr::select_if?` instead of `grep`.

Comment: This does work. But is there any way to delete the old variables at the same time? Transmute deleted ALL remaining variables, but I just want to get rid of those that have been used to make the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `tidyverse` syntax

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
     select(matches("AUS")) %>% 
     reduce(`+`) %>%
     mutate(df1, AUS_sum = .)
#   VAR1 VAR2 AUS1 AUS2 AUS3 AUS4 AUS56 VAR3 VAR4 AUS_sum
#1    A    D   23  234   34  856    99    0  FCK    1246
#2    B    D   55   76   55   36  6456    0  XYC    6678
```

---

With the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released `0.6.0`) we can create a function with `quosures` and make it more dynamic.  Here, the `enquo` does similar functionality as `substitute` from `base R` by taking the input arguments and converting it to `quosure`, with `quo_name`, we convert it to string where `matches` takes string argument.  The lhs name can also be created as string ('newN') and within the `mutate/summarise/group_by`, we unquote (`!!` or `UQ`) to evaluate the string

```
fSum <- function(dat, pat){
  pat <- quo_name(enquo(pat))
  newN <- paste0(pat, "_sum")
  newSum <- dat %>%
            select(matches(pat)) %>%
            reduce(`+`)
  dat %>%
      mutate(!!newN :=  newSum)
}

fSum(df1, AUS)
#    VAR1 VAR2 AUS1 AUS2 AUS3 AUS4 AUS56 VAR3 VAR4 AUS_sum
#1    A    D   23  234   34  856    99    0  FCK    1246
#2    B    D   55   76   55   36  6456    0  XYC    6678
```

Based on the OP's comment on the other post about removing the columns that used for `sum`, we can modify the function

```
fSumN <- function(dat, pat){
  pat <- quo_name(enquo(pat))
  newN <- paste0(pat, "_sum")
  newSum <- dat %>%
            select(matches(pat)) %>%
            reduce(`+`)
  dat %>%
       select(-matches(pat)) %>%
       mutate(!!newN :=  newSum)
}

fSumN(df1, AUS)
#     VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 AUS_sum
#1    A    D    0  FCK    1246
#2    B    D    0  XYC    6678
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(VAR1 = c("A", "B"), VAR2 = c("D", "D"), AUS1 = c(23L, 
55L), AUS2 = c(234L, 76L), AUS3 = c(34L, 55L), AUS4 = c(856L, 
36L), AUS56 = c(99L, 6456L), VAR3 = c(0L, 0L), VAR4 = c("FCK", 
"XYC")), .Names = c("VAR1", "VAR2", "AUS1", "AUS2", "AUS3", "AUS4", 
 "AUS56", "VAR3", "VAR4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Nice. Also you could just do `mutate(sum1 = rowSums(.))` after `select`

Comment: The first gives me an error message: `Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "reduce"`. The second one, honestly, looks rather complicated for such a simple operation.

Comment: @Laubsauger If you loaded `tidyverse`, the `library(purrr)` should get loaded.  The function is from that package.  THe second one is using non-standard evaluation making it more simpler when compared to the earlier versions with `interp` and stuff like that.  Function have the advantage of using multiple times with multiple patterns

Comment: @Laubsauger  Also updated with a new function to `get rid of those that have been used to make the calculation`

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. But now that I we are the function option already, can all this be done in a loop, too? Because I actually have numerous variable groups, not only AUT. So can I do the following in one command: `wiot <- wiot %>% 
  mutate(AUS = rowSums(.[grep("AUS", names(.))])) %>% 
  mutate(AUT = rowSums(.[grep("AUT", names(.))])) %>% 
  mutate(BEL = rowSums(.[grep("BEL", names(.))])) %>% 
  mutate(BGR = rowSums(.[grep("BGR", names(.))]))`

Comment: @Laubsauger  It could be possible, but please check your question.  These new criteria was not mentioned in your post

Comment: if you have a new question, you can post one instead of updating the current one with new requirements. @Laubsauger

Comment: @mtoto, you're absolutely right. I've posted a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518958/rowsums-conditional-on-clumn-name-in-a-loop

Answer (score 0):

In base R:

```
df$AUS <- rowSums(df[,grep('AUS', names(df))])
```